# Jest watch but only updated test

Tags: jestjs

Is there a way to run Jest with watch, but only rerun the modified test?

This is what I want:

```
npm run test:watch
```

That script execute:

```
jest --watch
```

But If I modified one test, Jest rerun all the test in my project. How could I rerun only the test that I have modified?

I know that I can directly call to one test with:

```
jest __tests__/utils/myTest.test.js --watch
```

But my idea is to run all the test the first time, then stay watching for the changed tests.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the **p** option to watch certain files.

[image]